Retrive Django related table data based on entity type and id
I am having some difficulties to write this django queries. I have the following scenario.
I have three django models

User
Visitor
Participants

For each interaction of a user and a visitor, I add some participants
participant_id entity_type entity_id 
    1             user        1
    2             visitor     1
    3             user        1
    4             visitor     2
    5             user        1
    6             visitor     3

Entity type can be either user or visitor. How can I get related user and visitor data from entity id and entity type?

entity_id - it is an pk from user or visitor table, right?

@MaximDanilov - Yes.

If you can refactor your solution to generic-relations, the answer is easy, because django already implements solution for you:
class Participant(Model):

    entity_type = ForeignKey(ContentType)
    entity_id = CharField(_('Sourced object id'))

    content_object = GenericFields('entity_type', 'entity_id')

And after:
user_or_visitor = participant.content_object 

more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations
Don't forget that you are getting here the “N+1 queries” performance problem "by default" and should take care of it with GenericPrefetch().
more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#genericprefetch
If you can not change current project models:
Preparing data:
participants = Participant.objects.all()

visitors_ids = participants.objects.filter(entity_type="visitor").values_list('pk', flat=True)
users_ids = participants.objects.filter(entity_type="user").values_list('pk', flat=True)

users = User.objects.filter(id__in=users_ids).in_bulk()
visitors = Visitors.objects.filter(id__in=visitors_ids).in_bulk()

Here you have made only 2 database queries, but you have stored the objects in memory.
Somewhere later:
for participant in participants.objects.all():
    participant.entity = None
    if participant.entity_type == "visitor":
        participant.entity = visitors[participant.entity_id]
    elif participant.entity_type == "user":
        participant.entity = users[participant.entity_id]

Here you have made only one request to db.
Of course, I can offer a more complex queryset request solution, but in my opinion, simple is better than complex.

Thanks @Maxim Danilov! Will accept the answer soon.

Thanks once again for your reply @Maxim Danilov! The content(this not only contains the solution of using dynamic relation but also includes super query optimisation technique and the usage information) should be more than adequate and it is clearly putting me in the right direction. :)

@kta - you're welcome ;)
